# Potentiometer getting warm

Tags: resistance, potentiometer

I have a load (resistance 3.4Ω) connected to a 6-volt DC supply, with a 2-watt 100Ω potentiometer which is set to ensure the current flowing through the load is set to 200mA.

It works fine but the potentiometer starts to get warm after a while.

I assumed a 2-watt potentiometer would be sufficient (0.2A * 6V = 1.2W).

Am I doing my calculations incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you think the pot is going to dissipate the 1.2W?

Comment: Is it normal then for it to become warm?

Comment: Datasheet for the pot? The datasheet might tell you the thermal resistance of the pot so you can calculate the expected temperature of it while dissipating 1.2W.

Comment: at half capacity it will be pretty warm to the touch for sure

Comment: The datasheet is here - http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/91_95.pdf although I can't see anything relating to thermal resistance.

Comment: 1.2W is your total power. Load power = 0.136, so pot has to actually dump 1.064W,, not a big difference... but you did ask if your calculations were correct

Comment: This is all going to be terribly temperature sensitive. You would be better with some sort of current regulator.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers/comments. I think I may have to look at an alternative solution. Having said that, I've come across this on Amazon: https://www.amazon.co.uk/sourcingmap-Rheostat-Variable-Resistor-Watts/dp/B0087YL8VQ/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1495750442&sr=8-7&keywords=rheostat           I imagine heat could still be an issue though?

Comment: Your pot would run @ 1/4 W with an lm317 (0.2*1.25)

Comment: Ok. I'll look into the LM317. How did you get the 1.25?

Answer (score 3):

A 2 watt pot of 100ohms has a maximum permitted current of 140mA (\$I^2R\$=P, 0.14 * 0.14 * 100 = 2).

You are overloading the portion of track that's carrying the current, whether or not the total dissipation is below 2 watts.

Answer (score 2):

@Neil_UK (+1) has given you the conservative answer to prevent overloading a pot. Some well constructed pots can handle more than the number he states, but **you'll always be safe if you follow that rule of thumb**.

Here, from the Bourns Potentiometer Handbook you can see that their metal case pots can handle 50% of rated dissipation with only 20% of the element in play. Plastic case pots are limited to 20%. If in doubt, assume that derating is as Neil states.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your pot' is set to draw 200 mA from your 6 V supply.

So the total load resistance across the supply must be 30 ohms.

As the pot' is in series with a 3.4 ohm load, your pot' must be set to 26.6 ohms.

The pot' is rated for 2 W power dissipation.

As the pot' resistance is a long strip, your power is being dissipated in one particular quarter (26.4/100), not spread evenly across the whole 100-ohm resistance.

And the power dissipated in that quarter of the pot's resistance is 1.064 W.

You need a higher-rated pot' or a different way of doing things.

A higher-rated pot' would have to be at least 4 W without derating i.e. an allowance of extra capability to avoid running it continuously at its maximum.

Derating to 50 % means an 8 W pot'. And the heat is still in there.

A different way of doing things might be a power transistor mounted on a heatsink and controlled by a pot'.

Comment: Or figure out a fixed resistor / trimmer pot combination. Fixed R still needs to be beefy though.

Comment: Right, @Trevor, then again the power in the pot' depends on how much adjustment the OP wants/needs from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always compute the Thermal temp rise from the specs and fine print.

```
+70 °C Single Section Assembly ...(Linear tapers) 1 watt
     ............................ (Linear tapers) 2 watts
+125 °C ..........................................0 watt
```

..next page..

```
NOTE: Performance specifications do not apply to units subjected
      to printed circuit board cleaning procedures.

 1 At room ambient: +25 °C nominal and 50 % relative humidity
   nominal, except as noted.
```

Thus assuming you have the Cermet Element

- **2W @ 70°C with 25°C ambient means Rth=23'C/W**
- thus using 1.2W your **"warm" measurement is** 25°C + 1.2*23 **=53°C**

@Spehro makes a good point that plastic conductors need to be derated as they are thermal insulators.  But CERMET is at least 30% metal and 70% Ceramic but 100Ω Cermit will be a **much** better thermal conductor than metal film which is rated for only 1W.

So be wise about cautious about current.
[image]

**[Ref](https://www.bourns.com/pdfs/onlinepotentiometerhandbook.pdf)**

Warning

### Don't use a Pot for high current, just bias an emitter or LDO for CC.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an LM317 configured as a constant current regulator. The pot adjusts the current through the 317 but the heat is now dissipated by the 317 which is easily heatsinked. The pot can be a small trim pot if panel mounting is not required.